# glslc - Missing entry point even with -fentry-point

Tags: glsl, vulkan, spir-v

When using `glslc --targe-env="vulkan1.1" -fentry-point="mainColor" test.frag`, I get the error

> ```
> test.frag: error: Linking fragment stage: Missing entry point: Each stage requires one entry point
> ```

test.frag content :

```
#version 450

layout (location=0) in vec4 color;
layout (location=0) out vec4 fragColor;

void mainColor()
{
    fragColor = color;
}

void mainWhite()
{
    fragColor = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?
How to fix this compilation error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What am I doing wrong?*

See [Support multiple entry points in a single module #605](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glslang/issues/605):

> GLSL only allows a single entry point per stage, so either 0 or 1 per compilation unit, and it must be called `main()`. [...]

and [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification (HTML) - 3.8.2. Dynamically Uniform Expressions and Uniform Control Flow](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#definitions)

> [...] Uniform control flow is the initial state at the entry into `main()`, [...]

*How to fix this compilation error?*

Declare the `main()` function.

Comment: The main function is changing, I want to compile with mainColor as main in one binary, and then mainWhite in another one. It's what -fentry-point is expected to do, no ?

Comment: @Calvin-Ruiz Yes I know, this is possible in Vulkan as in SPIR-V, but it is not possible in GLSL: "*GLSL only allows a single entry point per stage, [...]"*

Comment: @Calvin-Ruiz This is not possible in the latest GLSL version (4.60), but may be it will be possible in the future.